# vim colorscheme is not working for a particular file

Tags: vim, color-scheme, vim-plugin

I'm using spf13-vim The Ultimate Vim Distribution. One of the my `c` files' `colorscheme` is not working. Now whole file is displaying like a commented block. I could not figure out which of my actions caused this problem. So if anybody has any idea, please share.
set filetype and set syntax is not showing anything.

```
:set filetype
```

filetype=

```
:set syntax
```

syntax=

Comment: Vim is probably using the wrong syntax. What file type is it and what does `:set filetype` and `:set syntax` give you?

Comment: The _colorscheme_ maps syntax groups to colors. From your (very incomplete) description, it rather looks like a problem with syntax highlighting; i.e. the file is parsed wrong. At least show us the values of `:set filetype? syntax?`, better the entire file.

Comment: Oh, and once romainl reads this, he'll lecture you on why you shouldn't use distributions: You'll lose control and have to deal with more complex configuration, just as in your case here.

Comment: No I won't, because you already did. ;-)

Comment: Your file is not recognized by Vim as a C file.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the suggestions.
Just removed the distribution, from now own I'll use my own .vimrc
:)

Comment: You're definitely better off without a distribution. The filetype wasn't detected, but then, there should be **no highlighting at all**, whereas you said _displaying like a commented block_. That's odd.